# How do you override def toString in Scala to print a List[List[Int]?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, tail-recursion

I am trying to write a function to override the `toString` function in Scala. I have a list of lists (`List[List[Int]]`) which I am trying to print. The `List[List[Int]]` is representing a sudoku grid. Each `List[Int]` represents a particular row. The override function is supposed to print the grid, replacing '0' with a '_'. I am expected to implement everything recursively. The following is my code:

```
override def toString() = {
def innerFn(li: List[Int], s:String): String = {
  if (li.tail.isEmpty) s+"\n"
  else {
    if (li.head == 0) innerFn(li.tail,s+"_ ")
    else innerFn(li.tail,s+li.head+" ")
  }
}

def outerFn(li: List[List[Int]], s: String): String = {
  if (li.tail.isEmpty) s
  else {
    if (li.tail.head.isEmpty) s
    else innerFn(li.head,s)
  }
}
outerFn(grid,"")
}
```

I believe that my "innerFn()" is working properly since it is printing the List[Int] as I need it. However, for some reason only the first row (or first element of the `List[List[Int]]`) is being printed. I cannot see what I am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recursive form

```
  val grid: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1, 2, 3), List(2, 3, 4))

  def toString() = {
    def innerFn(li: List[Int]): String = {
      li match {
        case x :: xs => li.mkString(",")
        case Nil     => ""
      }
    }

    def outerFn(li: List[List[Int]]): String = {
      li match {
        case x :: xs if (!xs.isEmpty) => innerFn(x) + "\n" + outerFn(xs)
        case x :: Nil                 => innerFn(x)
        case Nil                      => ""
      }
    }

    outerFn(grid)
  }
```

Comment: Many thanks. This is an assignment and I cannot use mkString. I have however slightly altered the outerFn() you provided and used it with the innerFn() I wrote. I got the desired result. The pattern matching for the outerFn() makes more sense than how I was reasoning it out. Thanks once again. @johny

Answer (score 2):

In scala we are creating wrappers to override base methods for specific type blends:

```
object Sudoku {
  implicit class GroupStr[X](xs: Seq[X]) {
    def groupStr(sep: String): String =
      xs.grouped(3).map(
        _.mkString(sep, sep, sep)
      ).mkString
  }
}

case class Sudoku(grid: List[List[Int]]) {
  import Sudoku._
  def lineSep = ("-" * 9).toList.groupStr("+") + "\n"
  override def toString = grid.map(_.groupStr("|") + "\n").groupStr(lineSep)
}
```

Now your can verify that

```
println(Sudoku(List.range(0, 9).map(
    i => List.range(0, 9).map( j => (i + j) % 9 + 1))))
```

prints

```
+-+-+-++-+-+-++-+-+-+
|1|2|3||4|5|6||7|8|9|
+-+-+-++-+-+-++-+-+-+
|2|3|4||5|6|7||8|9|1|
+-+-+-++-+-+-++-+-+-+
|3|4|5||6|7|8||9|1|2|
+-+-+-++-+-+-++-+-+-+
+-+-+-++-+-+-++-+-+-+
|4|5|6||7|8|9||1|2|3|
+-+-+-++-+-+-++-+-+-+
|5|6|7||8|9|1||2|3|4|
+-+-+-++-+-+-++-+-+-+
|6|7|8||9|1|2||3|4|5|
+-+-+-++-+-+-++-+-+-+
+-+-+-++-+-+-++-+-+-+
|7|8|9||1|2|3||4|5|6|
+-+-+-++-+-+-++-+-+-+
|8|9|1||2|3|4||5|6|7|
+-+-+-++-+-+-++-+-+-+
|9|1|2||3|4|5||6|7|8|
+-+-+-++-+-+-++-+-+-+
```

Another approach is using typeclasses like [`scalaz.Show`](http://docs.typelevel.org/api/scalaz/nightly/index.html#scalaz.Show$) also see [here](http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/Show.html)